# R Shiny app error : Warning in charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) : r of length 1 all but the first element will be

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to create a Shiny application in R, which gives us the choice to select a plot from a list of different plots and show the selected one in a bottom bloc, but when I launch it, i get the following error message :

```
Warning in charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored
```

the source code is  below :

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(faraway)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
   graph<-c("point","smooth","jitter","histogramme","bar"),
   # Application title
   titlePanel("Plot"),

   selectInput("var1","Variable 1 :",choices = colnames(worldcup),selected=colnames(worldcup)[3]),
   selectInput("var2","variable 2 :",choices = colnames(worldcup),selected=colnames(worldcup)[1]),
   selectInput("graph","plot type :",choices = c("point","smooth","jitter","histogramme","bar"),selected="point"),

      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  graph<-reactive(input$graph)
  the_plot<-reactive({
    if(graph=="point"){
      the_plot <- ggplot(worldcup,aes_string(input$var1,input$var2))
        +geom_point()
    } 
    if(graph=="smooth"){
      the_plot <- ggplot(worldcup,aes_string(input$var1,input$var2))
        +geom_smooth()
    }
    if(graph=="jitter"){
      thhe_plot <- ggplot(worldcup,aes_string(input$var1,input$var2))
        +geom_jitter()
    }
    if(graph=="histogramme"){
      the_plot <- ggplot(worldcup,aes_string(input$var1))
        +geom_histogramme()
    }
    if(graph=="bar"){
      the_plot <- ggplot(worldcup,aes_string(input$var1))
      +geom_bar()
    }
  })
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({the_plot})

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  For these types of errors/warnings on Shiny, I strongly suggest you strip down the server.R file to the minimum until you identify the misbehaving line.

Comment: yeah i have cleaned up my code and it works, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always find that the shiny errors are a little tough to decipher. Here is the code you're looking for and I'll explain all my changes after.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- shinyUI(
   fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Plot"),
      selectInput("var1","Variable 1 :",choices = colnames(mtcars),selected=colnames(mtcars)[3]),
      selectInput("var2","variable 2 :",choices = colnames(mtcars),selected=colnames(mtcars)[1]),
      selectInput("graph","plot type :",
           choices = c("point","smooth","jitter","histogramme","bar"),selected="point"),
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
       )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot<-renderPlot({
        if(input$graph=="point"){
        the_plot <- ggplot(mtcars,aes_string(input$var1,input$var2))+
            geom_point()
        print(the_plot)
       }
        if(input$graph=="smooth"){
        the_plot <- ggplot(mtcars,aes_string(input$var1,input$var2))+
            geom_smooth()
        print(the_plot)
       }
        if(input$graph=="jitter"){
        the_plot <- ggplot(mtcars,aes_string(input$var1,input$var2))+
            geom_jitter()
        print(the_plot)
       }
        if(input$graph=="histogramme"){
        the_plot <- ggplot(mtcars,aes_string(input$var1,input$var2))+
            geom_histogram()
        print(the_plot)
       }
        if(input$graph=="bar"){
        the_plot <- ggplot(mtcars,aes_string(input$var1,input$var2))+
            geom_bar()
        print(the_plot)
       }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

What I changed:

1. I changed the data to mtcars so that I could run the example
2. I removed the `graph` vector you made at the beginning because we don't need it
3. I got rid of `graph <- reactive({...})` because we don't need it.
4. I changed `the_plot<-reactive({...})` to `output$distPlot <- renderPlot({...})` because this is where we want to be making the plot.
5. In all your conditional statement I changed graph to input$graph because graph is an input.
6. I moved all of the `+` signs up to the `ggplot` call because this is where they need to go.
7. I added print statements to the plots to return the plot (This might not be necessary).
8. I changed `geom_hitogramme` to `geom_histogram()` because that is what worked for me.
9. You have an extra "h" in "the_plot" for jitter, so I changed that for consistency.

I know that seems like a lot, but most of the edits were pretty minor and and you weren't terribly far off. I'd recommend reviewing how the inputs and outputs work with shiny and when its appropriate to wrap something in reactive.

Comment: thanks dude it's working, the code i have pasted was so terrible cause i tried all different possibilities and i was so nervous cause nothings work, thank you again